How do I leverage /etc/cron.d/ from Alpine Linux?
In debian, I can drop crontab snippets into /etc/cron.d/foo, /etc/cron.d/bar, etc.
This is very important because it allows me to overwrite and update cron task chunks without interfering with the main crontab, any other programs, or any user cron jobs. That means I can install a package and maintain a package-specific crontab snippet from one version to another.
Now, I am porting this package onto alpine linux, and I've noticed that while I can get cron running, there is only support for the normal crontab, and not for /etc/cron.d (or so it seems).
While I can write a script to wipe out my package's cron job when I install new versions, and I can tag the crontab strings associated with my package to make that simpler, I'd rather take a discrete approach with a crontab snippet.
Is there any way to leverage the cron-snippet feature of /etc/cron.d, or will I absolutely have to write a script?

In order to scope this, I am absolutely writing a script to clean and update the crontab before considering any other method for scheduling than cron. So alternatives to cron, such as busybox, are out of the question.
